# jquery for image rotation in iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, objective-c, image, animation

I have seen the previous related stack posts for this...But i have a query regarding where should I put this code? means how can I use "script" and other HTML tags in iPhone ? May be it is a silly question but still I want to know

Comment: Exactly the same like on a regular browser. If you're building an App which shows a Webpage, just add an UIWebView and load the Page.

Comment: I am running my app in simulator...So is it possible?

Comment: it should be possible either way. The simulator and the real iPhone behave almost exactly similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "script" and any other HTML tags on the iPhone.
MobileSafari is a full featured browser, with a working javascript engine and some HTML5 support.
Where exactly you put that code, depends on the code itself.
Since you have not posted any reference to what code you are referring to, that question cannot be answered.

Comment: Actually I am just fresher....and I don't know about where I should put the HTML code.....In .h file or in .m file or where? Actually i am going to run my app in simulator and not in any browser...so..what should i do? May be my question is silly...But still....

Comment: .h and .m files are typical for C code projects, not for HTML ;)
javascript is interpreted, not compiled, which sets it apart from C.
if you need to learn about javascript and how to use it, take a look at http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/primer3.shtml

Comment: Thanks for this details...but my question is where should i put jquery code?....see I have created one view based app named sample App.It gives three files...     .m file, .h file and  .xib file    now on y first view I have to put jquery for Image slider....I have the whole Jquery code.....now my question is where should i put? Perhaps I have to write it in  .m file  but how? I have implemented jquery in java earlier so having idea about jquery.....

Comment: Ideally, you would embed the html and jquery code as separate .html and .js files, specifying those as resources.
(for instance, make a folder in your project named "html" and put them there.
You can then load those resources into a UIWebView using objective-c.